# How to get path of project using custom user control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created custom user control in WinForms, now I want to get path of project when I drag and drop custom user control to form of new project.

Example: `string path = UserControl1.ProjectPath;`.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Once you compile the code and and run, 'Project Path' has no meaning. Can you keep describe your case and what exactly you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Reflection` and the [CodeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase(v=vs.110).aspx) of the assembly

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(UserControl1).Assembly.CodeBase);
```

This will give you the folder that contains the DLL; which may or may not be in your project.

Comment: I doubt user is looking for this.